# Can't get search bar to go back up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have nav bar, with a search bar on top of it. When you want to search it'll appear. And when you're done it'll slide back up. The issue is, I can't get it to slide back up, I can only get it to slide down. Here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".icon-search").click(function(){
      $(".slip").toggleClass("slip-open"); 
      $("#FORM_1").removeAttr("style");
});
```

And a demo for the thing with CSS and markup http://jsfiddle.net/FjwPZ/2/

You'll see that the search bar slides down, but not back up. Any help would be great.

Comment: Change to $('#FORM_1').toggle();

Comment: I love when people get points for copying my comments 5 minutes later...oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `toggle()` instead of `removeAttr`

> Toggles each of the set of matched elements. If they are shown, toggle
>   makes them hidden. If they are hidden, toggle makes them shown.

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".icon-search").click(function(){
      $(".slip").toggleClass("slip-open"); 
      $("#FORM_1").toggle();
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FjwPZ/3/)**